# Java http request client example

Tags: java, http, request, client

I am new in computer networking and I have a exercise about create java http client example.

The exercise instruction:

```
Socket soc = new Socket(host, port);

DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(soc.getInputStream());
BufferedWriter out= new BufferedWriter(new 
OutputStreamWriter(soc.getOutputStream())); 

out.write(httpRequest);
out.flush();

String httpResponse= in.readUTF();
```

and this is my code:

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;


public class MyTest{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException, IOException{
        
        String host = "gg.gg";
        String httpRequest = "GET / HTTP/1.1 Host:gg.gg ";
        int port = 80;
        
        Socket soc = new Socket(host, port);
        
        
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(soc.getInputStream());
        BufferedWriter out= new BufferedWriter(new 
        OutputStreamWriter(soc.getOutputStream())); 
        
        
        out.write(httpRequest);
        out.flush();
        
        
        String httpResponse = in.readUTF();
        
        System.out.println(httpResponse);
        //soc.close();
    }
}
```

but when I run the program, it run very long time, and I found that is the readUTF() method.
It run about 20s then display this message:
[image: Debug detail]

Does my request "GET / HTTP/1.1 Host:gg.gg " not correct, or any another error here?
I want to use the instruction form, not another solution. Thanks! (I'm not good at English very much)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- An HTTP 'end of line marker' is CR LF or `\r\n`.
- The 'simple request' format is `Simple-Request = "GET" SP Request-URI CRLF`

You should do:

```
String httpRequest = "GET /\r\n";
```

In addition, `in.readUTF()` uses 'modified UTF-8' and is not what you want, as it expects the size of the string to be specified as the first 2 bytes.

While not *efficient*, this works:

```
int read;

while ((read = in.read()) != -1)
{
  System.out.print((char) read);
}
```

(This ignores the encoding that the response actually is, but it happens to come back as UTF-8 and that's perfectly fine for casting with `(char)`.  Proper encoding handling is out of scope for this answer.)